# MSTest exe 64 bit

Tags: mstest

I am using 64 bit window 10 operating system. I want to run nunit scripts without using visual studio. I have tried to install MSTest 32 bit exe and throwing exception due to OS version 64 bit. Please can anyone share the steps to proceed further without using visual studio. Please suggest is there any tool other than MSTest which helps to me resovle this. Also, can anyone share the links to download MSTest.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to compile Unit Test with **Any CPU** configuration

Update:
If your code or tests were compiled as 32-bit/x86, but you now want to run them as a 64-bit process, recompile them as Any CPU, or optionally as 64-bit.

For maximum flexibility, you should compile your test projects with the Any CPU configuration. Then you can run on both 32 and 64 bit agents.

From the Visual Studio menu, choose Test, then choose Settings, and then choose Processor Architecture. Choose **Any CPU** to run the tests in both 32 and 64-bit process.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Is it possible to elaborate more on Any CPU configuration.. I am new to this and got stuck....

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for the update....Also, when i try to execute the scripts through command prompt getting test method cannot be found.

Test TestingMethods cannot be found.
Test TestingMethods cannot be found.
Starting execution...
No tests to execute.

Please let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: i want to run nunit scripts where visual studio not installed..but i am getting   test method cannot found while running the commands in command prompt using MSTest exe. Could you please help on this.